# error with function missing a positional argument

Tags: python, function

I am getting an error in my program that says finddiscount() missing one required positional argument. I can't seem to figure out how to properly code the find discount function could someone please help? Im sure this is a simple error but I am new to python and especially new to functions. Thanks!

```
def finddiscount(discount):
        if quantity >= 1 and quantity <= 9:
            discount = "0%"
        elif quantity >= 10 and quantity <= 19:
            discount = "20%"
        elif quantity >= 20 and quantity <= 49:
            discount = "30%"
        elif quantity >= 50 and quantity <= 99:
            discount = "40%"
        elif quantity >= 100:
            discount = "50%"
        print (discount)    
    def main():
        quantity = int(input("How many packages where purchased?"))
        price = float(input("How much is each item?"))
        finddiscount()
        return
    def finddiscount(quantity):
        if quantity >= 1 and quantity <= 9:
            discount = "0%"
        elif quantity >= 10 and quantity <= 19:
            discount = "20%"
        elif quantity >= 20 and quantity <= 49:
            discount = "30%"
        elif quantity >= 50 and quantity <= 99:
            discount = "40%"
        elif quantity >= 100:
            discount = "50%"
        print (discount)    
    main()
```

Comment: For future reference, don't try to describe the error message, copy and paste the actual message, with its description and traceback. In a very simple case like this, people may be able to guess exactly what went wrong and where, but in general, that information in the error message is useful—even if it looks like Greek to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the cascade of if statements (and unexpected errors - what if quantity = 0? or 110?) like so:

```
import bisect
import sys

inp = raw_input if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000 else input

def type_getter(type_):
    def getfn(prompt):
        while True:
            try:
                return type_(inp(prompt))
            except ValueError:
                pass
    return getfn
get_int   = type_getter(int)
get_float = type_getter(float)

discount_points    = [     0, 10, 20, 50, 100]
discount_fractions = [.0, .0, .2, .3, .4,  .5]

def discount_fraction(qty):
    ndx = bisect.bisect_right(discount_points, qty)
    return discount_fractions[ndx]

def main():
    qty   = get_int("How many were purchased? ")
    price = get_float("How much is each?")

    frac = discount_fraction(qty)
    total = price * (1. - frac) * qty
    print("Final cost is ${:0.2f}.".format(total))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are invoking the function like this

```
finddiscount()
```

But it is defined like this

```
def finddiscount(quantity):
```

So, you should be passing a value for the `quantity` parameter.

```
finddiscount(quantity)
```

Answer (score 1):

You define the function as taking one parameter:

```
def finddiscount(discount):
```

(and later redefine it, but let's ignore that for now, since the second definition also takes one parameter).

But then you call it with no arguments:

```
finddiscount()
```

Presumably you wanted this:

```
finddiscount(quantity)
```

---

There are a number of other problems with your code. You shouldn't be defining all of this stuff inside a `finddiscount` function definition. And you definitely shouldn't be defining a local function named `finddiscount` inside a global function with the same name.

Also, you usually want your functions to actually `return` something, not just `print` a value and then do nothing. (For example, you might want to `return` the discount, so some later code can apply that discount to the `price`.)

But this will solve the problem you asked about.